# Hibernate Second Level Cache slowing down spring-data-jpa findAll()

Tags: performance, hibernate, caching, spring-data-jpa, second-level-cache

I am using **Hibernate second level cache with Hazelcast** as the caching provider. Everything works well with the **findOne()** statements and I can see the response time of my HTTP API reducing significantly. On the other hand, any API which causes a call to **findAll()** get slowed down significantly if caching is enabled. I am not using query cache.

I understand that the second level cache maps id->data hence **findOne()** would just fetch the data from cache which would make it faster. What would be happening when **findAll()** is invoked, especially since I am not using query cache (though I enabled query cache and still the response time remains the same). Why would second level cache increase the response time?

Response time with cache cleared: **10-15ms**

Response time with data cached: **510-520ms**

These numbers are from running the entire setup on localhost.

The settings are as follows:

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: 'off'
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          use_query_cache: false
          use_minimal_puts: true
          region:
            factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
          use_structured_entries: true
          generate_statistics: true
          hazelcast:
            instance_name: cafe-hz-instance
      javax:
        persistence:
          sharedCache:
            mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
```

Hazelcast Config

```
public Config localHazelcastInstance() {

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName(hazelcastConfigProperties.getInstanceName());
        config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true).setUrl(hazelcastConfigProperties.getManagementCenterUrl());

        getMapNamesWithExpiry().forEach((name, expiry) -> {
            MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
            mapConfig.setName(name).setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT).setBackupCount(2).setTimeToLiveSeconds(expiry).setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU).setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(200, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE));
            config.addMapConfig( mapConfig );
        });

        GroupConfig groupConfig = config.getGroupConfig();
        groupConfig.setName(hazelcastConfigProperties.getGroupName());
        groupConfig.setPassword(hazelcastConfigProperties.getGroupPassword());

        return config;
    }

private Map<String, Integer> getMapNamesWithExpiry() {
        return new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
            put("default", HazelcastConfigProperties.ExpiryTime.ONE_DAY.getValue());
            put("polygon_cache", HazelcastConfigProperties.ExpiryTime.ONE_DAY.getValue());
            put(CorporateUserMappingEntity.class.getName(), HazelcastConfigProperties.ExpiryTime.NEVER.getValue());
            put(CafeZoneEntity.class.getName(), HazelcastConfigProperties.ExpiryTime.ONE_DAY.getValue());
            put(CafeEntity.class.getName(), HazelcastConfigProperties.ExpiryTime.ONE_DAY.getValue());
            put(CorporateEntity.class.getName(), HazelcastConfigProperties.ExpiryTime.ONE_DAY.getValue());
            put(RestaurantEntity.class.getName(), HazelcastConfigProperties.ExpiryTime.ONE_DAY.getValue());
            put(OrderEntity.class.getName(), HazelcastConfigProperties.ExpiryTime.ONE_SECOND.getValue());
        }};
    }
```

Comment: multiple things could go wrong... add your second level cache settings to help. And how many entities are we talking about with findAll?

Comment: Added the settings. Right now there are only 2-3 entities in the DB.

Comment: Sorry I mean spring-data-jpa.

Comment: You do realize that the entities retrieved by `findAll` *will* all be cached, right? I'd start by comparing response times in the following scenarios: (1) the current setup, (2) `findAll` with `javax.persistence.cache.storeMode=BYPASS` query hint, (3) `use_minimal_puts` disabled. Check the results for repeated queries as well. This should give you an overview of how/why the cache affects performance in this case

Comment: Also, provided that you are not planning on using `use_structured_entries` or `generate_statistics` in production, it would be best to disable them for the time of benchmarking

Comment: @crizzis `javax.persistence.cache.storeMode=BYPASS` and `javax.persistence.cache.storeMode=GET` lead to performance getting back to normal. Which means the write of the findAll() results to the cache is what is slowing things down.

To check why that might be happening, I reduced the synchronous backup count of Hazelcast map to 0, but that didn't change anything in terms of performance.

Enabling query cache doesn't help as well, though I am not sure why. So I guess my question is this now, how can I use second level cache for a findAll() operation and let all results be served from cache.

Comment: Actually, enabling the query cache does work. I had not made the findAll() method cacheable explicitly which is why it was not getting cached. So yes, after caching the query result, I am able to get the performance gain without having to bypass the cache for writes.